# ec2 public DNS address is redirecting, and it shouldn't be

Tags: amazon-ec2

I started an Ami Linux install on a micro plan last week on AWS and installed Wordpress so I could tinker with it.

Things were going well, but then the Wordpress install couldn't be accessed via browser and I couldn't SSH in.

I wound up terminating the instance and re-creating three times. The last time I created a Volume before terminating, thinking I would be able to save the steps of re-creating my Wordpress install.

However, I've had issues with getting Apache to run (I was finally able to do so) and now when I use the Public DNS address (I'm not using a domain at this time as it's a sandbox) that the instance shows, it's taking me to the Public DNS that was with the install previously.

So - SSH is working just fine. It's just when trying to access the site via browser I get redirected to the Public DNS address that was associated with the Wordpress install previously.

Is my install just borked or is there something I can do to fix it?
Thanks

(btw - my linux skills are severely lacking, and I've used step by step tuts to get this far on the install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its wordpress doing redirect. During initial setup Wordpress is saving website address to its database. You may just add these lines to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

See Wordpress codex for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL